# SELECT query returns 0 rows in PHP and 1 row in phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am trying to execute pretty simple query:

```
SELECT `id` 
FROM `some_table` 
WHERE `field_1`=? AND `created` >= DATE_SUB(Now(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

- The 'field_1' in database table is VARCHAR(256).
- The 'field_1' parameter is string 256 characters long and includes only [a-fA-F0-9].

**PROBLEM**
If i run this query in phpMyAdmin I get 1 row as expected.
But if I perform this query in PHP script using mysqli prepared statements and `bind_param('s',...)` then `$stmt->num_rows` is always 0.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit #1**
Here is the PHP code:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($mysql_config['Host'], $mysql_config['User'], $mysql_config['Passphrase'], $mysql_config['Database']);
if ($mysqli -> connect_errno) {
    syslog(LOG_ERR, '...');
    exit;
}

if (!($stmt = $mysqli -> prepare('SELECT `id` FROM `some_table` WHERE `field_1`=? AND `created` >= DATE_SUB(Now(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)'))) {
    syslog(LOG_ERR, '...');
    exit;
}

if (!$stmt -> bind_param('s', $string_value)) {
    syslog(LOG_ERR, '...'); 
    exit;
}

if (!$stmt -> execute()) {
    exit;   
}

$stmt -> bind_result($id);
exit ('num rows is: ' . $stmt->num_rows);
```

And the output is always: num rows is: 0.

**FINALLY**
After reboot the WebServer (Amazon EC2 Micro - Amazon Linux + Apache 2.4 + PHP 5.5) all things became normal. Miracle.

Comment: We can't see your PHP, but it's probably incorrect.

Comment: Can you post your php script?

Comment: Sure. Sorry for the frequent editions. I just don't want to post the original code. :)

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is... =\